# Uncompress log.gz files

Tags: perl, gunzip

I wanted to uncompress multiple log.gz - files from yesterday.

The Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError) ;
use Time::Local;

#yesterday
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = (gmtime())[0..5];

my $yesterday_midday=timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) - 24*60*60;

($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year) = localtime($yesterday_midday);


my $path = sprintf "..\\..\\history\\%d\\%02d\\%02d\\*.log.gz",$year+1900, $mon+1, $mday;
print("PATH: $path\n");

gunzip '<path>' => '<#1.log>' #unzip all .log.gz files
        or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```

The Error:

```
Max wild is #0, you tried #1 at D:/Perl64/lib/IO/Uncompress/Base.pm line 545
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You need to expand the scalar `$path`.** In your case, you are telling gunzip to unzip a file named `path` into wild carded output. The error tells you that the **string "path" does not contain any wild cards**, yet you are referring to the matching wild card (which does not exist since there were no wild cards in "path" string).

Try this:

```
gunzip "<$path>" => '<#1.log>' #unzip all .log.gz files
        or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
```

Comment: Yeah my bad, edited. Single quotes will not interpolate the variable, it will take the string as it is literally.